# Does JSON.parse() require double quoting?

Tags: javascript, json, firefox

I'm using Firefox 3.5b4.

This alerts `[object Object],[object Object]`:

```
var jsonString = '[{"foo": "one", "bar": 1}, {"foo": "two", "bar": 2}]';
var jsonObjects = JSON.parse(jsonString);
alert(jsonObjects);
```

This alerts an empty string, i.e. jsonObjects is `null`.

```
var jsonString = "[{'foo': '1', 'bar': 2}, {'foo': '3', 'bar': 4}]";
var jsonObjects = JSON.parse(jsonString);
alert(jsonObjects);
```

Likewise for unquoted property names, i.e. `{foo: '1', bar: 2}`.

What's going on? Am I missing something obvious, or is there a rule about double and single quoting with `JSON.parse`? All three versions work OK with `eval`.

Answer (score 34):

The JSON standard mandates double quotes.

Remember that JSON isn't just "write a JS object".  It's a very strict syntax that happens to be also readable as a JS object.  Not every JS-valid syntax is valid JSON.  In fact, your example ins't really valid JSON, since it's an array of objects while the standard specifies that the top construct MUST be an object.

Of course, most JSON parsers are more flexible, allowing for non-standard options (like single quotes); but don't rely on that.

Comment: Where does it say the top structure must be an object? [This document](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627) gives an example of just an array, and [json.org](http://json.org/) doesn't seem to specify this requirement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4201631/977939 this has the explaination: reserve words.

Answer (score 3):

To add to what Javier said, JSON limits the format mainly for security reasons (so functions can't be called, etc.).  If you're not concerned about security, use javascript's "eval()" function to convert the string to an object.

Comment: Don't use eval if you plan on using this code in an add-on though.