# How do I access the value of a boolean property on a JSON object generated by Rails in an AngularJS expression?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**The scenario:**

I was using the `ng-class` directive on an element that had an `ng-repeat` directive.
I put the `ng-class` on my element to add a class to my element if some conditions were met.
The problem I encountered was with my conditions.  Since they had come from some JSON that
I had generated with Ruby on Rails, the keys in my JSON that returned booleans ended with
question marks.  When quoted, question marks are perfectly valid in JSON keys, but when I tried to access them in my AngularJS expression using dot-notation, the console in Chrome would show an error:

**The failing code:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="foo in bars" ng-class="{'boo': foo.bar.baz? || !foo.bar.yes? }">
```

**The error:**

```
Error: Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 39-39 [?] in expression
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution was to access JSON key value pairs via square-brackets, quoting the key names.

**The working code:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="foo in bars" ng-class="{'boo': foo.bah['baz?'] || !foo.bar['yes?'] }">
```

I discovered this solution while using AngularJS 1.0.5, Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 2.3.17

http://www.json.org/

Also a good discussion here:

[Is there any practical reason to use quoted strings for JSON keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201441/is-there-any-practical-reason-to-use-quoted-strings-for-json-keys)

Comment: still relevant solution for angular 1.3 and rails 4.1, cheers for reporting your solution