# Unable to json_decode an object I send with JSON.stringify()

Tags: php, json, stringify

I have a script that posts a large object with AJAX after `JSON.stringify()`.

When I am trying to decode it in PHP using `json_decode($object, true);` it won't be decoded.

My object looks something like:

```
var object = [
    {field_name:"Date &amp; Time", some_other_value:"somevalue1"}
]
```

I am fairly sure it has something to do with the `Date &amp; Time`. I am pretty sure that when I build the object, the value I insert into field_name is `Date & Time`

In PHP I've tried:

```
json_decode($object, true);
json_decode(utf8_decode($object))// with true as well.
json_decode(htmlentities($object, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

None seem to work.

UPDATE:
I used `alert()` on the stringify and this is what i get:

`"fields":{"29411502":{"id":29411502,"name":"Date &amp; Time","functionName":""}}`

Anyone with an idea ?

Comment: Your sample isn't technically valid JSON and wouldn't/shouldn't be generated by `JSON.stringify()`. (It's missing quotes around they property names.) Can you show us what the *actual* output of `JSON.stringify()` is?

Comment: yea will get the output 1 sec

Comment: I've updated the post the with string i get. Should have included it before. but why the down vote ?

Comment: Your update is not syntactically valid JSON.  At a minimum, it's missing a closing }.

Comment: yaps - it's a much bigger object i cut it wrong but its not the issue

Comment: Sounds like when you post, you are not using the text/javascript content type.  &amp's never get converted for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In-case someone cares about the solution:

I had to us `encodeURIcomponenet()`  on the stringified object.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the & characters is the PHP script suddenly able to decode the object correctly?

Is so, might you need double encoding on the ampersand character?  Is it possible it's getting decoded prior to the remainder of your message and causing a break in the parse?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
<?php

var_dump(
    json_decode(
        '[
            {"field_name":"Date &amp; Time", "some_other_value":"somevalue1"},
            {"field_name":"Date &amp; Time", "some_other_value":"somevalue2"},
            {"field_name":"Date &amp; Time", "some_other_value":"somevalue3"}
        ]'
    ),
    json_last_error(),
    PHP_VERSION
);

?>
```

Results in:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
    ["field_name"]=>
    string(15) "Date &amp; Time"
    ["some_other_value"]=>
    string(10) "somevalue1"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
    ["field_name"]=>
    string(15) "Date &amp; Time"
    ["some_other_value"]=>
    string(10) "somevalue2"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
    ["field_name"]=>
    string(15) "Date &amp; Time"
    ["some_other_value"]=>
    string(10) "somevalue3"
  }
}
int(0)
string(17) "5.3.15-pl0-gentoo"
```

Seems right to me...

Answer (score 0):

Works for me

test.html

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="js/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<button id="bob">Click ME</button>
<script>
(function($){
  $('#bob').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "test.php",
      data: JSON.stringify([{"this":"is &amp; test"}]),
      contentType: "text/javascript"
    }).done(function(a) {
      alert(a);
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.php

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");

var_dump($data);

var_dump(json_decode($data, true));
```

Produces a nice popup of

```
string(26) "[{"this":"is &amp; test"}]"
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    'this' =>
    string(13) "is &amp; test"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

place single quotes around parameter and value

```
var object = [
{'field_name':'Date &amp; Time', 'some_other_value':'somevalue1'},
....
```

Comment: Nope that's not it..  its something with the &

Comment: Should be double quotes, not single quotes, per JSON spec.  See eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201441/is-there-any-practical-reason-to-use-quoted-strings-for-json-keys