# unable to load plugin jquery-visible using requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, requirejs

i am using require.js for my project and unable to load the ["jquery-visible"](https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible) plugin, i configured the path correctly with jquery.visible.min

```
require.config({
    paths: {

        'jquery': "../kendo/js/jquery.min",

        'dependency':"../jquery-visible-master/jquery.visible.min"
    },
```

and defining the dependency like this

```
define(
    [
         "jquery"

         ,"dependency"

    ],
    function (
         $

       ,dependency

    )
```

when i use the dependency to call the jquery function(.visible) it is saying .visible() is not a function

```
$("#bookmark-5").visible() ;
```

error message in console :  **456 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).visible() is not a function**

Answer (score 1):

Try to use next config:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: "../kendo/js/jquery.min",    
        dependency :"../jquery-visible-master/jquery.visible.min"
    },
    shim: {
        dependency: ["jquery"]
    }
```

Comment: Vladimir, in your paths and shim objects you don't use quotes on the property names, am I doing it wrong if I use quotes?

Comment: @MikeDevenney, no - that's fine. Moreover - seems like you're right. Check this discussion - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201441/is-there-any-practical-reason-to-use-quoted-strings-for-json-keys

Comment: Thanks for the link, I hadn't done much digging yet as I just started using the library as part of a new project.  Good to know!