# Invalidate JSON object for keys without quotes in c#

Tags: c#, .net, json, validation, json.net

In javascript this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201441/is-there-any-practical-reason-to-use-quoted-strings-for-json-keys?rq=1) JSON.parse(json) will validate to fail
Is there any alternative in c# when quotes are not provided for names in json object. (names indicate keys in keyvalue pairs)

```
{
    name: "s"
}
```

should fail validation where as

```
{
    "name": "s"
}
```

should pass validation

Tried with Newtonsoft.Json's JObject.Parse(body); but it automatically adds quotes and passes validation.
I'm trying to validate according to JSON Standard [RFC 4627](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) in c#. Wondering if there a facility to fail validation in case of not providing quotes for keys in c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured out the solution on my own.

```
    public bool ValidateMissingDoubleQuotes(string json)
    {
        using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json)))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                return !(reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName && reader.QuoteChar != '\"');
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```