# Writing key and value in json

Tags: javascript, json

I am very new to javascript. We can write json as follows

```
const obj1 = {key: "myKey", value: "myValue"}  
const obj2 = {"myKey": "myValue"}
```

what is a difference between these two?
And when should I prefer using one over another?

Comment: There is definitely a difference. Please ignore all the answers below saying otherwise, and instead read the second answer to the duplicate question.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, it doesn't matter. It's up to you.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a difference. Write however you want. I personally prefer the key not to be a string.`var a = {key: "value"}`

Comment: Strictly speaking there is a difference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201441/is-there-any-practical-reason-to-use-quoted-strings-for-json-keys