# Parse a file of strings in python separated by newline into a json array

Tags: python

I have a file called `path_text.txt` its contents are the 2 strings separated by newline:

```
/gp/oi/eu/gatk/inputs/NA12878_24RG_med.hg38.bam 
/gp/oi/eu/gatk/inputs/NA12878_24RG_small.hg38.bam
```

I would like to have a json array object like this:

`["/gp/oi/eu/gatk/inputs/NA12878_24RG_med.hg38.bam","/gp/oi/eu/gatk/inputs/NA12878_24RG_small.hg38.bam"]`

I have tried something like this:

```
with open('path_text.txt','w',encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
    myfile.write(','.join('\n'))
```

But it does not work

Comment: You say you want to ***read*** the file to JSON, but your code is ***writing*** to the file. Which one are you actually trying to do? If you're trying to read, why not just `file.readlines()`?

Comment: read yes. I'm sorry, I was trying to write comma (,) and double quotes (") into the existing file. thats why i used write

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list) followed by [How do I write JSON data to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see where you're actually reading from the file in the first place. You have to actually read your `path_text.txt` before you can format it correctly right?

```py
with open('path_text.txt','r',encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
    content = myfiel.read().splitlines()
```

Which will give you `['/gp/oi/eu/gatk/inputs/NA12878_24RG_med.hg38.bam', '/gp/oi/eu/gatk/inputs/NA12878_24RG_small.hg38.bam']` in `content`.

Now if you want to write this data to a file in the format `["/gp/oi/eu/gatk/inputs/NA12878_24RG_med.hg38.bam", "/gp/oi/eu/gatk/inputs/NA12878_24RG_small.hg38.bam"]`-

```py
import json

with open('path_json.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(content, f)
```

Now the `path_json.json` file looks like-

```json
["/gp/oi/eu/gatk/inputs/NA12878_24RG_med.hg38.bam", "/gp/oi/eu/gatk/inputs/NA12878_24RG_small.hg38.bam"]
```

which is valid json in case you want to load a json from a file

Comment: @Tomerikoo true, I have no idea how I managed to forget using `json.dump` in my answer at first while simultaneously mentioning it in a comment

Comment: @Chase yeah I noticed that in the moment ^_^ All good... now it looks fine :)

Answer (score 3):

see below

```
with open('path_text.txt') as f:
    data = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
```

Comment: list comprehension is good but note that single quotes are the result, JSON needs double quotes

Comment: We have list of strings here. The quote type in not important.

Comment: @alex what? single quotes are just how python represent strings, that does not mean anything at all. That will still be valid json when you use `json.dumps`

Comment: @Chase I think the OP is confused with single-quotes ***when reading a file*** that can't be read as JSON

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883243/does-json-parse-require-double-quoting

Comment: JSON requires double quotes, guys I just want to copy and paste the result into a json file

Comment: @alex then why don't you use the built-in `json` module?

Comment: @alex check my answer then

Comment: @Tomerikoo show me please how to do that with such file. would be great to see it. You mean `json.dump()`